# Microsoft Teams Tags in Power Apps

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps

How is it possible to show the tags that are assigned to a team member in Microsoft Teams, in a text label for a selected person in Power Apps?

Ideally I would like to do it without using Power Automate, but if that is the only way, please tell me how I can achieve it.

I tried it with different functions, but I haven't found the one, where I can see the tags.

Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the members of a standard tag in a team and their properties using following graph API

```
GET /teams/{team-id}/tags/{teamworkTag-id}/members
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktagmember-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http